# Changing the color of an object (UV sphere)

Tags: properties

I've been enjoying my first hours with Blender so, my question is super simple. I am trying to make a neon loop with the sun on the horizon. How do I change the color of the sun only, without changing the color of the surroundings?

I added the Emission Surface and changed the color but in the result I got all the surroundings modified.

[image]

[image]

Could you tell me the right steps?

Happy quarantine :)

Answer (score 0):

It's okay if you don't set the world material to emission.
In world panel, you can select background option instead of emission and you can increase the strength of the background to make it brighter and brighter. You can also set any colour you want to the "world background"

To make the sun, you can make a emissive uv sphere, by the way i would recommend to make the sun circular instead of spherical (because the sun is very far from the earth so we see the orthgraphic image of spherical sun which is circular).

So to make the sun you can add a circle and fill it to get a solid face. Now set an emission material to your sun.

In eevee mesh lighting don't work so you will have to place the sun lamp or point lamp or plane lamp to simulate the lighting.
You can turn on bloom, screenspace reflections, and depth of field if you want.

Links:
https://youtu.be/hnLsktA4gmY

https://youtu.be/FsETUAsiI7c

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this simple gradient texture world shader work for you?

You can control colors via the color ramp, brightness of sun/backkground via the corresponding value nodes, size/diffuseness of the sun via the X location and scale of the Vector Mapping, position in the sky via Z and Y rotations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know! =) I will check those nodes